# cant push project to github, master -> master (fetch first)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github

I created the react.js and node.js projects and want to add them to github, like this is the file structure

[structure file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiEO4.jpg)

i want to add it to github but when I push there is an error like this

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9aSv.png)

why could it happen like that? how to handle it?

after i fetch i got new error

master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Comment: The error is right there on your screenshot, have you tried following its suggestion?

Comment: yeah but still, after I tried fetch it still can't do the push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you are **completely** sure that you want to push that changes to the repo, you can do

`git push -f origin master`